# ¡Encadenar varios eventos en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

¡Muy buenas!, es que estaba intentando hacer que se ejecutara el evento mousedown siempre que se este presionando el click izquierdo en un determinado elemento, de momento lo intente hacer con el documento en si, pero resulta que el mousedown solo se dispara una vez... yo lo que necesito es que siempre que se presione el click izquierdo y se este moviendo el mouse se ejecute determinada función para saber las coordenadas del mouse (Necesito que se estén actualizando todo el tiempo siempre y cuando se cumplan las condiciones anteriores).

Pense en encadenar un evento con otro de esta manera:

```
class Brush{

   //Constructor y demás cosas

   paint(ev){

       ev.target.onclick = ev2 =>{

           /*El resultado de esto es que solo se ejecuta una vez cuando hago click
             Es como si ignorara el otro evento y no me imprimiera lo que 
             necesito*/
           console.log(ev2);

       }

   }
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove",ev => brush.paint(ev));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la propiedad `buttons` de un evento de ratón puedes obtener si esta clickando sobre algún botón del mismo. (1 = izquierdo, 2 = derecho)

```
paint(ev){

    if (ev.buttons === 1) {

        /*El resultado de esto es que solo se ejecuta una vez cuando hago click
        Es como si ignorara el otro evento y no me imprimiera lo que 
        necesito*/

        //ev2 reemplazado a ev ya que ev2 ya no existe en el contexto actual
        console.log(ev);

    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me funcióna a la perfección esta solución. Sin embargo tuve que cambiar la linea del console.log(ev2); ya que ev2, ya no existe, existe es ev, hay que editar esa parte por si otras personas intentan usar esta respuesta tal cual no les genere error.